# Convert false to undefined (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I have a variable called isApp.

If isApp is true I wish to do the following:

```
login({os:"ios"})
```

If isApp is false, I wish to call:

```
login()
```

How can I do this as a one liner in javascript?

```
login(isApp&&{os:"ios"})
```

is not correct as it calls login with false if isApp is false. I wish to call it with undefined.

**UPDATE**

I have other arguments going to login so I don't wish to write login twice.

for example:

```
login({tokenId:200}, {os:"ios"})
```

therefore I don't like this solution:

```
isApp:login({tokenId:200}, {os:"ios"})?login({tokenId:200});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `undefined` using the conditional operator:

```
login({tokenId:200}, isApp ? {os:"ios"} : undefined);
```

If the *number* of arguments you're passing matters, you'll need to either call `login` in two branches or use `apply`:

```
var args = [{tokenId:200}];
if (isApp) {
    args.push({os:"ios"});
}
login.apply(null, args);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to pass a parameter based on the boolean `isApp` and than you can add the rest of your params:

```
login(isApp ? {os: "ios"} : undefined);
```

Comment: I have other arguments going to login so I don't wish to write login twice.

Answer (score 3):

How about `login(isApp ? { os: "ios"} : undefined);` ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following minimalistic style:

```
login(isApp && {os: "ios"} || undefined, secondParam);
```

It basically does the same as ternary operator, but with different flavour :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use conditional operator

```
isApp ? login({os:"ios"}): login();
```

Comment: I have other arguments going to login so I don't wish to write login twice.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14063116)

Comment: @rajeshujade it was the answer for his question. Later he edited his question.You can see the edit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
isApp = ![];//false
login( {token:{id:200}} , !isApp ? [][[]] /*-->undefined*/ : {os:"ios"} );
```

Comment: What's the point of the `[][[]]` construct instead of simply typing the literal `undefined`?